# How can hypochlorous acid produce the hydroxide ion?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism

Hypochlorous acid ($\ce{HOCl})$ is an acid so it should produce $\ce{H+}$. However in reactions with alkenes, it produces the hydroxide ion like bases do. How is this possible? What is the mechanism?

Comment: Come to think of it, water gives $\ce{H+}$ like acids do. But at the same time it gives $\ce{OH-}$.

Comment: If you think about it, alkenes react with $\ce{Br-Br}$ to form a bromonium ion, and $\ce{Br-}$, right? Now, if you hypothetically replaced one of the $\ce{Br}$ with $\ce{OH}$, you'd get a bromonium ion and $\ce{OH-}$. $\ce{Cl-OH}$ is not all that different. You get a chloronium ion and $\ce{OH-}$.

Comment: Not a cation with $\ce{OH}$ plus a chloride ion?  How do we know which end is positively polarized?

Comment: you've made a nice comparison orthocresol but I wanted to know about the mechanism of the reaction

Comment: Oscar Lanzi it is HOCl gives Cl^+ and OH^-